# Teamcity deployment: pass Revision Number to MSBuild

Tags: deployment, msbuild, teamcity

I use TeamCity as a Build Server and want to pass the revision number from 
svn to my msbuild script. The reason is that I want to create a directory on
a test / staging server with this number.

I've googled with bing (and google ;)) but couldn't find a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of teamcity do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `%build.vcs.number%` contains the svn revision number.

Under command line parameters for an MSBuild runner you can pass this value.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the build number is already passed to msbuild have you tried the retrive it with:

```
$(BUILD_NUMBER)
```

Another option is to use build parameters:

[Configuring Build Parameters](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+Build+Parameters)

From the page above:

*.... a convenient way of passing generic or environment-specific settings into the build script.*

The build parameters are automaticly append to the msbuild command line, for example:

```
msbuild.exe test.sln .... /property:foo=bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need both of the above answers to achieve what you want. You need to set you teamcity build to use %build.vcs.number%  so that when you parameter BUILD_NUMBER is set to that value.